# Восстановление после вируса Amnesia Ransomware базы 1с повреждена 1 часть файла вирусом шифровальщиком

Tags: sql, база-данных, шифрование, вирусы, восстановление

поймал шифровальщик, все бекапы и базы зашифрованы 1c бекапы делались в формате dt.
Проанализировав зашифрованные файлы выяснилось что вирус шифрует только первый мегабайт или небольшую часть файла и добавляет в конце файла еще код.

Собственно нужен совет статьи форумы куда писать кто чем может помочь помогите. (я тоже сейчас активно ищу способы в интернете может кто сталкивался) Сейчас вижу только 2 способа:

1. Расшифровать, что сразу отпадает опыта не было поэму пока буду стараться 2ым способ, а потом уже 1ым
2. Удалить зашифрованные элементы и скрестить их с рабочим файлом у нас базы и по 1гб и по 9гб (нужно разобраться в dt формате и перевести к виду который прочитает хотя бы без начальных данных базы

П.С. Подозреваю что каждый файл имеет свой ключ шифрования динамический который зашифрован в конце файла который тоже зашифрован статическим ключем который знает знает вирус, возможно этот ключ и есть id в блокноте который оставили в каждой папке (если этот вирус супер автономный). Что мало вероятно атака была 9 мая по 10 на бюджетное учреждение т.е. они знали когда нападать. (следов вируса не нашел похоже он себя грохнул) Файлы датируются 2 ночи по 8 утра может еще раньше есть.
Также есть зашифрованные активные базы 1с базы sql сервера активные и архивные (зашифрованные). Прочитал про dt хреновый формат вроде как может лучше пытаться восстановить активные файлы 1с.

Все зашифрованные файлы начинаются на `G.` первые 2 байта.
Симптомы вируса `Scarab-Amnesia` текстовые фалы с требование почти такие же только id 8-10 символов сейчас не помню домой не взял файлы

UPD Выяснялось что базы были на sql сервере

Comment: сисадмина обидели?

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос не совсем по тематике форума https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, но учитывая глубину Вашей проблемы, видимо стоит оставить все на усмотрение сообщества.

Comment: @Александр Муксимов, подскажите пожалуйста форумы такие же могучие  по теме, не zuk где сидят хакеры школьники, я просто не сижу на форумах вообще писал пару вопросов на этом форуме тут люди более менее адекватные просто

Comment: Это совершенно не моя тема, но исходя из здравого смысла, я бы закинул удочку на форумы производителей антивирусов. Кроме того, с учетом "...следов вируса не нашел похоже он себя грохнул..." -  версия об обиженном сисадмине, исходя из нравов современного мира,, не выглядит не вероятной.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, а сисадмин здесь причем? Сисадмин, как я вижу, та еще лалка! Это как-раз таки допустил этот так называемый "сисадмин".

Comment: @Тема, напишите мне вк, /misdeed

Comment: Sql сервер это хорошо. Пока он работает - он не дает подпортить файлы простыми вирусами